# Php error in downloading file kept on server

Tags: php

I am using following code to download a file kept on server ....now my issue is that i am not able to download file when some thing address like "*http:127.0.0.0/upload/abc.pdf*" file ....but i am able to download file using upload/abc.pdf i want to download my file from different folder kept on different server with different address with php on different server how can i do it .....help is must needed ...thanks in advance....

```
<?php
    function output_file($file, $name, $mime_type='')
    {
     //if(!is_readable($file)) die('File not found or inaccessible!');
     $size = filesize($file);
     $name = rawurldecode($name);

     /* Figure out the MIME type | Check in array */
     $known_mime_types=array(
        "htm" => "text/html",
        "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
        "zip" => "application/zip",
        "doc" => "application/msword",
        "jpg" => "image/jpg",
        "php" => "text/plain",
        "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
        "gif" => "image/gif",
        "pdf" => "application/pdf",
        "txt" => "text/plain",
        "html"=> "text/html",
        "png" => "image/png",
        "jpeg"=> "image/jpg"
     );

     if($mime_type==''){
         $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
         if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types)){
            $mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
         } else {
            $mime_type="application/force-download";
         };
     };

     //turn off output buffering to decrease cpu usage
     @ob_end_clean(); 

     // required for IE, otherwise Content-Disposition may be ignored
     if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
     ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
     header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($name).'"');
     header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
     header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

     // multipart-download and download resuming support
     if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
     {
        list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
        list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
        list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
        $range=intval($range);
        if(!$range_end) {
            $range_end=$size-1;
        } else {
            $range_end=intval($range_end);
        }

        $new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
        header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
        header("Content-Length: $new_length");
        header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
     } else {
        $new_length=$size;
        header("Content-Length: ".$size);
     }

     /* Will output the file itself */
     $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); //you may want to change this
     $bytes_send = 0;
     if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))
     {
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
        fseek($file, $range);

        while(!feof($file) && 
            (!connection_aborted()) && 
            ($bytes_send<$new_length)
              )
        {
            $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
            echo($buffer); 
            flush();
            $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
        }
     fclose($file);
     } else
     //If no permissiion
     die('Error - can not open file.');
     //die
    die();
    }
    //Set the time out
    set_time_limit(0);

    //path to the file

    /*$c=$_REQUEST['filename'];
    $path=basename($c);
    echo $path;
    $file_path='uploads/'.$path;
    */
    $file_path=$_REQUEST['filename'];

    //Call the download function with file path,file name and file type
    output_file($file_path, ''.$_REQUEST['filename'].'', 'text/plain');
    ?>
```

`enter code here`

Comment: it is not clear what's the point. anyway the correct url should be "http://127.0.0.1/upload/abc.pdf" please read [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) for further info

Comment: hey i have changed the url to http://192.168.1.6 also the problem is not with url but whenever i pass an url address file is downloaded but it is blank....

Comment: The comment environment corrected my text. The url I suggested was: `http://127.0.0.1/upload/abc.pdf` double slashed.